# How to iterate over a list of components with ngFor

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to iterate over a list of components in a template.
The components have templates themselves.
How do I get the templates of the components to be added to the "parent" template?

I tried a lot of answers from the angular-dart tutorial and various other questions regarding angular-js and angular but none of them worked.

My first idea was to do the following:

ElementList Component

```
@Component(
  selector: 'element-list',
  template: '''
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let element of list">
      {{ element }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  ''',
  directives: [coreDirectives],
)
class ElementList{
  List<Element> list;

   ElementList(){
      list = [Element(), Element()];
   }
}
```

Element Component

```
@Component(
  selector: 'element',
  template: '''
  <li>
    {{ text }}
  </li>
  ''',
)
class Element{
  String text = 'test';
}
```

But this only displays:

- Instance of 'Element'
- Instance of 'Element'

What to I have to do to make it display:

- Test
- Test

The exact files where I'm trying to apply this are here:

[List Component](https://github.com/openrqm/openrqm-client-desktop-nwjs/blob/angular-dart/lib/components/rqm_workspace_tree.dart)

[Element Component](https://github.com/openrqm/openrqm-client-desktop-nwjs/blob/angular-dart/lib/model/rqm_workspace.dart)

Comment: Have you tried make a toString method in your Element class? Just something like: String toString() => text;

Comment: @julemand101 this would not solve the core problem. I would expect that a solution in angular-dart is awailable that allows to solve this with native angular-dart mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it would be the cleanest way to resolve this, but have you tried access the list attribute of your controller? Like this:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'element-list',
  template: '''
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let element of list; let i = index"">
      {{ list[i] }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  ''',
  directives: [coreDirectives],
)
class ElementList{
  List<Element> list;

   ElementList(){
      list = [Element(), Element()];
   }
}
```

Comment: This results in exactly the same behaviour as in the question. It displays "Instance of Element" instead of calling the constructor of element or whatever makes the template to be used in angular-dart

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange way to use Angular. I get the impression that you are trying to make Angular work like some other framework works.

I would refactor the code so that the template generates multiple `<elements>` that accepts their data as `[inputs]`, rather than instantiating '''Elements''' in the Dart code and trying to shoehorn them into the template.

I can't prove it is impossible to do what you are trying to do, but I am sure that it isn't the Angular way of doing it.

Comment: By your answer i found the solution. Thanks for pointing me into the direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I changed the code to create a new `<element>` for each item in the list and put the text of the item into the element component by an @Input() directive.

Additionally I had to add the Element class to the directives of the ElementList template.

element_list.dart

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

import 'package:angular_app/components/element.dart';
import 'package:angular_app/components/element.template.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'element-list',
  template: '''
  <ul>
      <element *ngFor="let element of list" [text]="element.text"></element>
  </ul>
  ''',
  directives: [coreDirectives, Element],
)
class ElementList {
  List<Element> list;

  ElementList() {
    list = [Element(), Element()];
  }
}
```

element.dart

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'element',
  template: '''
  <li>
    {{ text }}
  </li>
  ''',
)
class Element {
  @Input()
  String text = 'test';
}
```